# Why is `-dev` version of ruby required for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, rvm

When I was updating my gems, I ran into problems and I could not get my bundle to work on production.

The gem that did not install was `bcrypt`.
I am using RVM so in order to install `bcrypt` I had to change the ruby version from

```
2.2.1
```

to

```
2.2.0-dev
```

Now I could install `bcrypt` and my machine is up and running again.
However, what I don't understand, is why the `dev` version of ruby is required to run a rails application.

**Update**:

The Error I got when installing bcrypt:

```
Error installing bcrypt:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: *"ran into problems" / "did not install"* - please be more specific.

Comment: @Stefan I did update my question.

Comment: Have you tried the latest 2.2.x Ruby? 2.2.4? What version of bcrypt are you trying to install/update? What happens when you run `gem install bcrypt`

Comment: @Besi Bundler usually provides some helpful information in addition to the error notice. Something like *"Results logged to ..."* and *"Make sure that ... succeeds before bundling"*